# How to connect Thingsboard and Thingsboard IoT Gateway over SSL/TLS?

Tags: ssl, keystore, truststore, thingsboard

I need some help connecting a Thingsboard IoT Gateway with my Thingsboard Instance over a TLS 1.2 secured connection.

Thingsboard and the IoT Gateway are running on separate machines. Thingsboard is configured to only accept TLS 1.2 secured connections.

I started with the configuration of the IoT Gateway by following the "Getting Started" section in the documentation (https://thingsboard.io/docs/iot-gateway/getting-started/). This ended in an error message like:

```
2019-02-13 15:20:24,796 [main] ERROR o.t.g.s.gateway.MqttGatewayService - Unable to connect to ThingsBoard. Connection timed out after [10000] milliseconds
```

Reading some issues on GitHub I figured out maybe there has to be a specific configuration with keystore files. The target Thingsboard server is using a Let's Encrypt certificate. And in my JAVA cacerts keystore, the ISRG Root X1 certificate is included. Will the IoT Gateway not use this keystore? Do I have to provide a dedicated keystore file for the IoT Gateway?

Looking at the configuration page (https://thingsboard.io/docs/iot-gateway/configuration/) I still have a lot of questions. I never worked with keystore files and therefore I don't have any clue what certificates I have to add to a keystore file and how this is done.

This is my current **tb-gateway.yml** configuration:

```
server:
  # Server bind address
  address: "0.0.0.0"
  # Server bind port
  port: "9090"

# Check new version updates parameters
updates:
  # Enable/disable updates checking.
  enabled: "${UPDATES_ENABLED:true}"

gateways:
  tenants:
    -
      label: "IoT Community"
      reporting:
        interval: 60000
      persistence:
        type: file
        path: storage
        bufferSize: 1000
      connection:
        host: "thingsboard host address"
        port: 8883
        retryInterval: 3000
        maxInFlight: 1000
        security:
          accessToken: "token"
      remoteConfiguration: true
      extensions:
        -
          id: "http"
          type: "HTTP"
          extensionConfiguration: http-config.json
```

Can someone give me a more detailed explanation than the Thingsboard documentation?

Greetings,
Ben